# Why does my hover state stay activated after I animate an element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have button that when clicked moves to left. This part works great but I am confused as to why the hover state stays active until I move the mouse. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGz4p/) of the problem. Click on the button and don't move your mouse, notice that the hover state is trigger even after the animation is complete.

Here is my code
HTML:

```
<a href="#">Click</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
color: white;
background: blue;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;

}
a:hover{
background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var aW = $(this).outerWidth();
  $(this).animate({
      'left': aW
  });
});
```

Comment: Probably because hover-state is driven by [mouse events](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/FGz4p/1/) and those events aren't fired when you animate an element out from underneath the cursor...

Comment: Yes, you will need to force something with javascript. Like `$(this).css('background','blue');` on click event.

Comment: a:hover{
background: green;
} you have already CSS3 hover function, why re-apply from jquery?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, @canon is right, the mouse events don't fire. I will just have to leave it as it is for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the actual text 'link' have the property as default as width 100%(screen wide) and default height .So when you click it you will still actually hovering the text. If you click it and move your mouse far out, the hover effect will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
Use cloneNode() function.
Once you click the button, create clone of it.
Trigger the animation on the clone element.

Reason:
The element when hover will kept its event but the clone element does not.